# BroadcastReciever not working or AlarmManager not setting

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to set up a BroadcastReceiver with an AlarmManager, and just for testing purposes have it trigger 2000 miliseconds after. However, nothing is happening

Main class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, test_class.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Log.d("ALARM_DE","Set for: "+System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000);
        AlarmManager alarmManager =
                (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000 ,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Recieving class

```
public class test_class extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.
        }
        Log.d("ALARM_DE","Time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".test_class" android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: yup! just updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem! I simply added `intent.setAction("NOTIFICATION");` after initializing the intent and it went through! Any string should do the job :)

Comment: No sir, I tested all the way around this, and found other people with the same bug. I could not have missed the logs as they had a unique tag. This was 100% the problem

Comment: I don't understand; this change fixed it for me. I removed it and it doesn't work, I also tested with notifications AND logs, and it only works with this line. What else could have possible been the problem?

Comment: I tried this on my physical device as well as my emulator, both seem to have the same problem. And no worries!

Comment: Just added a toast after the log and it shows! Trying to figure out how to send the notification itself now though :/

Comment: Amazing! It worked flawlessly I appreciate the referral!

Comment: Everything works well but for some reason it still needs the action!

Comment: yeah seems to make sense! It was giving me a nullpointer exception when I remove it now!